# Unable to dockerize nginx and index.html page

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I try to follow this [tutorial](http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/). So, these are my prerequisites:

1. ubuntu version is 16.04.1 LTS
2. docker version is 1.12.6
3. docker-compose version 1.9.0

My local directory looks like so:

```
\code
    index.html
site.conf
docker-compose.yml
```

The index.html contents is just "Hello world".

The site.conf contents:

```
server {
    index index.html;
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;
}
```

The docker-compose.yml contents:

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
  - "8080:80"
  volumes:
  - ./code:/code
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
```

And finally in my /etc/hosts file I added to the top this line:

```
php-docker.local    127.0.0.1
```

With all that, when I run this command:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

And go to `php-docker.local:8080`, I get "Server not found" error. If however I go to `localhost:8080` I see a standard welcoming nginx page. So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it? Or what can I do to debug it?

Comment: Which docker are you using? Docker directly on Linux? Docker for Mac/Windows? docker-machine? You mentioned `/etc/hosts` - you meant on the main host system, or inside the container?

Comment: I solved the problem. Unfortunatelly, the tutorial that I used has a lot of errors. The whole problem is that instead of site.conf it should be nginx.conf and its contents should be totally different. But now I'm getting problems related to PHP (I will devote a new question to it)